# What to do to store recording stream into the mobile browser using Media Recorder API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, mediarecorder

I have a project requirement to record and store the currently running video stream. I have used webRTC for video streaming, and to record the video streaming, I have used MediaRecorder API. It is completely working fine in the desktop system. But it is not working in the mobile browser.

Any idea why it is not working in the mobile browser?

Following is the code snippet:

```js
componentDidMount = async () => {
                recordingStream =  await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                  video: true,
                  audio: true,
                });

                const mergedAudio = await this.mergeAudioStreams();
                console.log("audio track length... ", mergedAudio.length);
                const tracks = [
                  ...recordingStream.getVideoTracks(),
                  ...mergedAudio,
                ];

                captureStream = new MediaStream(tracks);
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(captureStream, options);
                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.handleDataAvailable;
                mediaRecorder.start();
       
}

handleDataAvailable = async event => {
    console.log("data-available", event);
    if (event.data.size > 0) {
      recordedChunks.push(event.data);
      this.download();
    } else {
      // ...
      console.log("in else");
    }
  };
  
 download = async () => {
    console.log("in download fn");
    var blob = await new Blob(recordedChunks, {
      type: "video/mp4",
    });
    
    
    //called the API to store the recorded video
}

mergeAudioStreams = async () => {
console.log("recordScreen fn called");

const ctx = new AudioContext();
const dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
let localSource, remoteSource;

if (this.state.localStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
  localSource = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(this.state.localStream);
}

if (this.state.selectedVideo.stream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
  remoteSource = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(
    this.state.selectedVideo.stream
  );
}

const localGain = ctx.createGain();
const remoteGain = ctx.createGain();

localGain.gain.value = 0.7;
remoteGain.gain.value = 0.7;

localSource.connect(localGain).connect(dest);

remoteSource.connect(remoteGain).connect(dest);

console.log("combine tracks..", dest.stream.getAudioTracks());

return dest.stream.getAudioTracks();
  };
```

Comment: Does your device [support the MediaRecorder API](https://caniuse.com/mediarecorder)?

Comment: Yes, It is supported.

Comment: Then you probably should describe, what exactly is not working. In particular a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (including the device type it does not work on)

Comment: @A_A, I have edited my question and provided the code snippet. Please check it. I have tested in android chrome's latest version.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. I won't be able to help (as I don't have android chrome), but now it should be easier for others to help you. If possible, make the code snippet runnable by just clicking "Run code snippet" (currently there's a SyntaxError)

Comment: Okay, Thank you @A_A. I will update my code snippet

Comment: @A_A, it will be great if you check the code for iOS. If you have iOS. Because my client has iOS itself.